# Why my virtual method is not overridden?

Tags: c++, overriding

```
class Base
{
public:
Base()
{
cout<<"base class"<<endl;
fun();
}
virtual void fun(){cout<<"fun of base"<<endl;}
};

class Derive:public Base
{
public:
Derive()
{
cout<<"derive class"<<endl;
fun();
}
void fun(){ cout<<"fun of derive"<<endl;}
};

void main()
{
Derive d;
}
```

The output is:

```
base class
fun of base
derive class
fun of derive
```

Why the second line is not `fun of derive`?

Comment: Reading material: ["Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction"](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `fun()` in the base class constructor, the derived class has not yet been constructed (in C++, classes a constructed parent first) so the system doesn't have an instance of Derived yet and consequently no entry in the virtual function table for `Derived::fun()`.

This is the reason why calls to virtual functions in constructors are generally frowned upon unless you *specifically* want to call the implementation of the virtual function that's either part of the object currently being instantiated or part of one of its ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

Because you wrote it like that... Your call to the derived class constructor does:

```
- Base Class Constructor call
   |
   Call to **fun of Base Class**
- Derived Class Constructor call
   |
   Call to **fun of the Derived Class**
```

More details [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html)

Comment: Isn't a virtual method in base class always overriden by a derived method with the same signature,even in constructor?

Comment: Yes, but the answer has just been given by Timo :)