# Why is my Object still using a method even though I have overriden it?

Tags: c#, decorator

**Possible Repeat**: [Why my Virtual method is not overriden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404978/why-my-virtual-method-is-not-overriden)

I've been going through the Head First Design Patterns. On a side note, I started this book as a prerequisite to Code Complete 2. Anyway, I'm working with the Decorator pattern ([the chapter can actually even be read online)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf).

So, I have 4 classes:

1. Beverage Class - Abstract
2. Espresso Class - Inherits Beverage
3. BeverageDecorator Class - Abstract
4. Mocha Class - Inherits Beverage Decotrator

Here is the source code for classes 1, 3, 4.

**Beverage Class:**

```
    public abstract class Beverage
{
    public Beverage()
    {
        Description = "Unknown Beverage";
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return Description;
    }

    public abstract double cost();

    public String Description { get; set; }

}
```

**BeverageDecorator Class:**

```
    public abstract class BeverageDecorator : Beverage
{
    public new abstract String getDescription();
}
```

**Mocha Class:**

```
    public class Mocha : BeverageDecorator
{
    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public override string getDescription()
    {
        return beverage.Description + ", Mocha";
    }

    public override double cost()
    {
        return beverage.cost() + .20;
    }
}
```

So they are pretty straight-forward. Then when I put this code in the Main() method I keep getting an "Unknown Beverage" description.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Beverage beverage = new Espresso();
        beverage = new Mocha(beverage);
        Console.WriteLine(beverage.Description +
            " $" + beverage.cost());

        Console.Read();

    }
```

**Mocha** goes from the class it inherits - Beverage Decorator - to the class above that - Beverage Class. Even though I have the method in the Beverage Decorator and I override it. Why is this happening? I know it has something to do with being abstract classes but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789783/overload-resolution-of-virtual-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two problems. Firstly, it looks like your `Description` property should call `getDescription` rather than the other way round. And then `getDescription` needs to be virtual in the `Beverage` class and *overridden* in `BeverageDecorator` rather than *hidden*.

It doesn't help that your code looks like a mixture of C# and Java. For example, do you really *need* a `Description` property *and* a `getDescription` method? Admittedly it's slightly tricky to override half a property (at least, I always get confused about the exact rules) but it's *definitely* odd to have camelCased names in C# code.

Here's an alternative implementation (no decorator class - it's not clear how that was meant to help):

```
using System;

public abstract class Beverage
{
    public Beverage()
    {
        Description = "Unknown Beverage";
    }

    private string description;

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }
}

public class Espresso : Beverage
{
    public Espresso()
    {
        Description = "Espresso";
    }
}

public class Mocha : Beverage
{
    private readonly Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get { return beverage.Description + ", Mocha"; }
        set { /* Ignored */ }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Beverage espresso = new Espresso();
        Beverage mocha = new Mocha(espresso);
        Console.WriteLine(mocha.Description); // Prints Espresso, Mocha
    }
}
```

Comment: You caught me that I'm still very new to the C# language, and in fact the book I'm using is writing in Java. Therefore, I just self-interpreted/translated the code they had given me in the book. This worked though and I see why (and also why mine didn't). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You have not overridden it truely.  You have used the `new` operator to hide a member below it.  The one problem with that operator is that if the caller uses a reference to the type that holds the member that is hidden later on, it bypasses the hiding.  In your case, it is when you use `Beverage` and expect to see the overridden result:

```
Beverage beverage = new Espresso();        
beverage = new Mocha(beverage);        
Console.WriteLine(beverage.Description + " $" + beverage.cost());
```

To override something, that something needs to be `virtual` or `abstract` and the overriding member needs to use `override`.  Your member isn't abstract or virtual, and in your derived class you have `new string getDescription` not `override string getdescription`.

So in your code when you talk to `Beverage` it ignores the hiding done in `BeverageDecorator`.

A bigger discussion on the decorator pattern, the decorating class doesn't need to inherit from what it decorates.  Usually it is done by taking the decorated class as a construction parameter.  If you need decoration and also some polymorphism, consider using an interface in conjunction with it:

```
interface ICommonStuff
{
    string getDescription();
}

public class Beverage : ICommonStuff { }

public class BeverageDecorator : ICommonStuff
{
    public BeverageDecorator(Beverage b) { }
}
```

But then, do you really need decoration?  This is something I ask frequently around the holidays...

Comment: I should have quickly seen that I can't override methods that aren't declared abstract or virtual. I am still rather new to programming and especially C#. I'm just using the code and techniques from the book and translating them from Java to C#. I maybe should have asked on the book's forum, but, I love StackOverflow! This book is probably not the best but that's why I'm only using it for an introduction to these patterns.

Comment: @Adam Beck head first design patterns is a good book for this thing.  However, if you are also new to C# I'd advise picking up some books on that too.  You chose the correct place to ask the question - you'd get no faster response from anywhere else :-)

Answer (score 2):

> public new abstract String getDescription();

This is **not** a method override, it's a new method unrelated to the `getDescription` method in the base class.

`Beverage.getDescription` can't be overriden, because it's not virtual. Declare it like that instead:

```
public abstract String getDescription();
```

or like that:

```
public virtual String getDescription()
{
    return Description;
}
```